# Create a C symbol alias of a C++ template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, ld

I need to generate many wrappers with C linkage of the form:

```
  int myfunc (type0 param0, type1 param1, ..., typeN paramN) {
       return (*g_libc.myfunc ## _fn) (param0, etc...)
  }
```

So far, I got away with lots of macros:

```
  #define NATIVE(name,...) \
  auto name (FULL_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  {                                                             \
    return (*mystruct.name ## _fn) (ARGS (__VA_ARGS__));              \
  }
```

but I would like to use variadic templates in C++11 for various reasons. I have a working variadic function that could replace the previous *hackish* implementation:

```
#define NATIVE(name) template <typename... Args> \
auto name (Args&&... args) -> decltype( name ( std::forward<Args>(args)...) ) \
{ \
  return g_libc. name ## _fn (std::forward<Args>(args)...); \
}
```

but then I would lose the C linkage (since templates can't have C linkage). My idea is thus to create an alias with the wanted function name that points towards the templated function.
It seems possible to have a C symbol as an alias of a C++ function (might seem obvious but I had to test it and it worked ok). However to be able to alias the templated function, I need to know its mangled name at compile time, which seems hard to get right (no gcc extension to do that, notwithstanding I want to support clang as well). My conclusion is that I should add the alias as a postprocessing step.

So the question is how to add a symbol alias to an already built shared library ? (I can 'grep' the 'nm' output to retrieve the mangled symbol)

Best regards

Comment: Function template is not a function, it doesn't by itself have a name that another module can link to. Function template instantiations, with concrete template arguments, are functions. I don't think templates would be helpful in your quest; your original, non-template-using, example makes much more sense.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. The motivation for using templates is very specific to the project I try to update: the project generates some kind of fake libc. If I use the macro version, I need to explicitly set the arguments "NATIVE(name,...)" while the template one can deduce the arguments types from the function name only since the functions are already declared in standard header. Typically, I want to be able to write "NATIVE(printf)" instead of "NATIVE(printf, const char*, ...)"

Comment: No, a template can deduce argument types from the function **call**, not the function name alone. Which doesn't help you, as the call is apparently in some C module which of course wouldn't know anything about templates.

Answer (score 2):

The macro should create another kind of mangled function name with C linkage which calls the C++ function. Making it inline removes the performance issues.

Comment: I don't think that's doable as my goal is to get rid of the macros and I don't see how this new intermediate function could pass the parameters to the C++ function without the macros. Let me know if the objective is not clear. Thanks for your time